# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). How to use it?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

**I was trying gray level slicing.**

**This is my whole code, I am trying to convert the image into gray scale without disturbing the background:**

```
def without_background(img_path, save_path):
    image = Image.open(img_path)
    img_array = np.array(image,dtype=np.uint8)
    img_shape=(image.width,image.height)
    display(image)
    
    for i in range(img_shape[1]):
        for j in range(img_shape[0]):
            v = img_array[i][j]
            if(v>=0 and v<=50):
                print(img_array[i][j]
                img_array[i][j]=255
            else:
                img_array[i][j]=0

    resultImage = Image.fromarray(img_array)
    resultImage.save(save_path)
    display(resultImage)
```

**This is error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a6d36de00a06> in <module>()
      2         for j in range(img_shape[0]):
      3             v = img_array[i][j]
----> 4             if(v>=0 and v<=50):
      5               print(img_array[i][j])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `v` is an array. The truth value of an array is ambiguous.

Comment: Please add code piece which does read image (create `img_array`) to your question

Answer (score 1):

Images have `three dimensions`. see this example you know where you are wrong. if you want check `v` you need iterate over `v` like below:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('1.png')
img_array = np.array(image,dtype=np.uint8)
print(img_array.shape) # (820, 892, 4)


img_shape=(image.width,image.height)
for i in range(img_shape[1]):
    for j in range(img_shape[0]):
        v = img_array[i][j]
        print(type(v.shape)) # <class 'tuple'>
        for k in v: # add this line
            if (k>=0 and k<=50):
                print(img_array[i][j])
                img_array[i][j]=255
            else:
                img_array[i][j]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `img_array[i][j]` returns an `np.array` (and not just a single value), because it returns the RGB values of the pixel.

If your image is already grayscale and all 3 values are identical, you can just take e.g. the first one (red) like this:

```py
v = img_array[i][j][0]
```

If your image is not yet grayscale you probably want to take the average for each value:

```py
v = img_array[i][j].mean()
```

... or potentially do some more complex math on it.

### What the error actually means

Let's take this little example:

```py
>>> arr = np.array(range(4))
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> arr > 1
array([False, False, True,  True])
```

What we get back from this comparison is not just a single boolean value, but an entirely new `np.array` filled with the result of each single comparison. Basically expanded like this:

```py
[0 > 1, 1 > 1, 2 > 1, 3 > 1]
```

When you now try to convert this `np.array` into a single boolean value...

```py
>>> if arr > 1: # which basically does: bool(arr > 1)
...   pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

... you get exactly this error.

You have two options, which the error message kindly provides you:

1. Use `(arr > 1).all()` which is true if *all* values are greater than 1.
2. Use `(arr > 1).any()` which is true if *any* value is greater than 1.